# Sound dies on Wine games

Tags: 11.10, sound, 64-bit, wine

I've been playing some old classic games (think 1999-2002) on Wine on Ubuntu 11.10 amd64 lately. The gameplay is great, but sound only works for a little while then crashes and doesn't come back until I restart the game. Log output from Wine doesn't show anything significant.

Is there a setting or a library I need to set to native in order to get things working? How can I debug this and find out what the problem is so I can find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command:

```
winecfg
```

Then, change into the audio tab, and make sure 'Alsa' is checked. Then click the button a little below to see if the sound is now working.